# Byte length of a string in xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Is there any xslt function to retrieve the byte length of a string.

For. e.g: `i ♥ u`

Character length obtained by string-length = 5
Byte length which I need = 7 bytes.

Comment: In which encoding do you want to compute the byte length? A string does not have a byte length without considering a particular encoding. See whether http://expath.org/spec/binary#encode-string can help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is support for the EXPath binary module then you can use `bin:length(bin:encode-string('i ♥ u'))`, as in

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:bin="http://expath.org/ns/binary">

    <xsl:template name="main" match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="for $enc in ('UTF-8', 'UTF-16') return bin:length(bin:encode-string('i ♥ u', $enc))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's another approach (again assuming UTF-8 encoding):

```
sum(for $c in string-to-codepoints($in)
    return (1 + number($c>127) + number($c>2047) + number($c>65535)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also play some tricks with `iri-to-uri()`.

Try this:

1. Apply `iri-to-uri()` to the string
2. Convert any `%xx` sequences in the result to a single ASCII character using the `replace()` function
3. The length of the resulting string is the number of bytes in the UTF-8 representation of the original string.

For example `string-length(replace(iri-to-uri('§'), '%..', '%'))` => 2

Also tested on your example.